# Can't debug Netsuite Restlet

Tags: netsuite

I cannot seem to debug a restlet.  I keep getting the error:

```
INVALID_HOST
Invalid host debugger.netsuite.com. Please send RESTlet requests to https://rest.netsuite.com/.
```

Even though my deployment list the external URL as:
`https://debugger.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl?script=58&deploy=1` and its status is "Testing"

I log into debugger.netsuite.com, click to use an existing script and it provides me with a cookie.  I add this cookie to my HTTP request header and am still returned the above error.

The request header I'm sending is:

```
Cookie: NS_VER=2012.1.0; JSESSIONID=$session_id
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: NLAuth nlauth_account=$account_id,nlauth_email=$email,nlauth_signature=$password,nlauth_role=
```

Does anyone know why I can't connect to the debugger?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above, having an "Authorization" header along with the Cookie will produce the error you see. Also, make sure of the following:

- The RESTlet is deployed in "testing" mode
- You are the owner of the RESTlet
- Your Netsuite account is enabled for debugging. Not 100% sure on this, but I have two logins, and only one was able to successfully debug a RESTlet.

Comment: What you mean with `I have two logins` do you mean for production and the sandbox? Or do you have two accounts for the sandbox? What about the host when sending the request, do I need to use the `debugger.sandbox.netsuite.com`? or can I leave it to `sandbox.netsuite.com`?

Answer (score 0):

You may not need this any more but the NetSuite online Help has a page specifically addressing how to debug your RESTlet in the NetSuite Debugger. It describes the process as logging into the Debugger server, then clicking "Debug Existing", then letting your script run. This way, the debugger knows how to help you. Your way, you're trying to run the script through the debugger server but not giving it a chance to grab that script's execution and control it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Look for Advanced Rest Client in the google webstore. The service is free and works very well when debugging Netsuite Restlet.

Answer (score 0):

Your on the right track. You just have to remove your Authorization data as you are already using the Cookie from Debugger to authenticate.

This solution is already available as well in SuiteAnswers